# Indefiniteness of $\omega _1$

Tags: set-theory

Can someone help me how to prove that $\omega _1$ is indefinite.

The thing is that I have always worked with proving that a certain term or $\in$-formula is definite, for which I was simply following the definition.

Here, the definitions are the following:

Let $ψ(v)$ be an $∈$-formula and let $t(v)$ be a term, both in the free variables $v$.

Then

a) $ψ$ is definite iff for every transitive ZF− model $(M , ∈)$

$∀x ∈ M (ψ^M(x)↔ψ(x))$

b) $t$ is definite iff for every transitive ZF− model $(M ,∈)$

$∀x ∈ M$ $t^M(x) ∈ M$ and $∀x ∈ M $ $t^M(x ) = t(x )$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the 'true' (in contrast to the relative) $\omega_1$ (or rather the 'true' singleton $\{ \omega_1 \}$) were definable without parameters, say by the $\mathcal{L}_{\in}$-formula $\phi$. Fix an ordinal $\alpha$ large enough such that $\omega_1 \in V_\alpha$, $\phi$ is absolute between $V$ and $V_\alpha$ (i.e. for all $x \in V_\alpha \colon \phi(x) \iff V_\alpha \models \phi(x)$) and $V_\alpha \models \operatorname{ZF}^-$. Such an ordinal $\alpha$ exists - basically by the [Reflection Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle). Now let $X \prec V_\alpha$ be a countable, fully elementary substructure such that $\omega_1 \in X$. Note that we now have $(X; \in \restriction X) \models \phi(\omega_1)$. Let
$$
(M; \in \restriction M) \overset{\pi}{\cong} (X; \in \restriction X) \prec (V_\alpha; \in \restriction V_\alpha)
$$
be the transitive collapse and fix $\beta \in M$ such that $\pi(\beta) = \omega_1$. Since $M$ is countable and transitive we have that $\beta < \omega_1$ is a countable ordinal. Moreover, by elementarity $(M; \in \restriction M) \models \operatorname{ZF}^-$ and, by the elementarity of $\pi$
$$
(M; \in \restriction M) \models \phi(\beta).
$$

Since $\beta < \omega_1$, this is the desired contradiction.

Comment: If you wonder what the 'true' in my first sentence means: There is a formula $\phi$ that identifies for every transitive $\operatorname{ZF}^-$ model $M$ that has $\mathcal P(\omega)^M$ the ordinal $\omega_1^M$. But as you see, this ordinal may not be the correct $\omega_1$ of our background universe.

Comment: Thanks! And what about the power set of $\omega$. I suppose it is indefinite as well, but for this, I need to have in mind transitive model of ZF- which does not contain all subsets of $\omega$. Is there even any such?

Comment: Sure, basically the same proof works. Just let $\alpha$ be large enough such that in addition $\mathcal P(\omega) \in V_{\alpha}$. Then, in $M$, there is some preimage of $\mathcal P(\omega)$ but this set - whatever it is - has only countably many members (as viewed in $V$) - so it cannot be $\mathcal P(\omega)$.

Answer (score 2):

Take any transitive model of $\sf ZF$, let $M$ be a countable elementary submodel, then $M$ is probably not transitive, but its Mostowski collapse is.

Show that it is necessarily the case that $\omega_1^M$ is collapsed to a countable ordinal. Conclude the wanted conclusion from that.